# search strings and label search terms in pandas efficiently

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have about 6millions rows and 500 search terms. For each search term I want to  find out which of these 6million rows partially matches with it. There are multiple matches for each search term too.

My data looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
searchterms = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear']
tosearch = {'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'Item':['aassseapplekk', 'orangee', 'peear', 'banana', 'appleorange', 'fruitpear']}
df = pd.DataFrame(tosearch)
print(df)
```

I want to know which search terms returns the matches, and return something like this

```
ideal =  {'ID':[1,2,5,5,6],'Item':['aassseapplekk', 'orangee', 'appleorange', 'appleorange', 'fruitpear'], 'searchterms':['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'orange', 'pear']}
ideal_df = pd.DataFrame(ideal)
print(ideal_df)
```

I've tried the following - not sure how it scales up to millions records and any ideas how I can find out which search item returns the result?

**Trial 1: use regex pipe to search all search items**

```
pattern = '|'.join(searchterms)
mock = df[df['Item'].str.contains(pattern)]
```

**Trial 2: loop to append search results of each term**

I'm still unsure about this loop since I don't seem to be able to substitute each item in my search list in 'i' and append to the empty list afterwards.

```
match = []
for i in searchterms:
    searchterm_match = df[df['Item'].str.contains(r'i', regex=False)]
    match.append(searchterm_match)
```

Comment: This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/select-by-partial-string-from-a-pandas-dataframe) might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use extractall to extract the pattern and then merge the result back to the df

```
pat = '('+'|'.join(searchterms)+')'
df.merge(df.groupby('ID')['Item'].apply(lambda x: x.str.extractall((pat))).reset_index([1,2], drop = True)[0].reset_index(name = 'searchterms'))


    ID  Item            searchterms
0   1   aassseapplekk   apple
1   2   orangee         orange
2   5   appleorange     apple
3   5   appleorange     orange
4   6   fruitpear       pear
```

Comment: thanks it works on the sample dataframe. For my understanding what does `pat` do?

Comment: pat is creating a pattern of strings by concatenating items in your list