# filter based on partial string for multiple columns headers

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following `Dataframe`:

```
           AAA3 ABB3 DAT4 DEE3 ABB4 AAA4 DAA3 EAV3 DAC4 DEE4
01/01/2020  1    1.1  1.5  1.2  1.32 1.2  1.2  1    0.9  0.5
02/01/2020  1    1.1  1.5  1.2  1.32 1.2  1.2  1    0.9  0.5
03/01/2020  1    1.1  1.5  1.2  1.32 1.2  1.2  1    0.9  0.5
04/01/2020  1    1.1  1.5  1.2  1.32 1.2  1.2  1    0.9  0.5
```

The values are not important, so I am giving all columns the same value.

What I want to do is see if the alphabets characters part of my `columns` `headers`, has an match among the headers, and if it does, remove the header that has an 4, leaving only the name that has a 3.

```
For example:
```

There is an `AAA3`, as well as an `AAA4`. I want to drop the  `AAA4` column, leaving only `AAA3`.

Note that there is a column named `DAC4`, but there isn't a `DAC3`. So I want to keep my `DAC4` column.

I couldn't solve my problem with the following question :
[Select by partial string from a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/select-by-partial-string-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a mask on duplicated of alphabet part. Create another mask where the last char is `3`. Finally slicing using these masks

```
m = df.columns.str.extract(r'(^[A-Za-z]+)').duplicated(keep=False)
m1 = df.columns.str.endswith('3')
df_final =  df.loc[:,(~m | m1).values]

Out[146]:
            AAA3  ABB3  DAT4  DEE3  DAA3  EAV3  DAC4
01/01/2020     1   1.1   1.5   1.2   1.2     1   0.9
02/01/2020     1   1.1   1.5   1.2   1.2     1   0.9
03/01/2020     1   1.1   1.5   1.2   1.2     1   0.9
04/01/2020     1   1.1   1.5   1.2   1.2     1   0.9
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain what (r'(^[A-Za-z]+)') means ?

Comment: @khouzam: it's the regex pattern for getting all alphabetic chars both uppercase and lowercase ignore digits. The `^` to indicate starting from the front.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Get a dictionary of similar columns :

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

d = defaultdict(list)
for entry in df.columns:
    d[entry[:-1]].append(entry)

d

defaultdict(list,
            {'AAA': ['AAA3', 'AAA4'],
             'ABB': ['ABB3', 'ABB4'],
             'DAT': ['DAT4'],
             'DEE': ['DEE3', 'DEE4'],
             'DAA': ['DAA3'],
             'EAV': ['EAV3'],
             'DAC': ['DAC4']})
```

Step 2: Get columns that end with 4 :

```
from itertools import chain

cols_to_drop = list(chain.from_iterable([[ent for ent in value 
                                         if ent.endswith("4")]
                                         for key,value in d.items() 
                                         if len(value) > 1]))

cols_to_drop
['AAA4', 'ABB4', 'DEE4']
```

Step 3: Drop columns :

```
df.drop(columns=cols_to_drop)

    AAA3    ABB3    DAT4    DEE3    DAA3    EAV3    DAC4
0   01/01/2020  1   1.1 1.5 1.2 1   0.9
1   02/01/2020  1   1.1 1.5 1.2 1   0.9
2   03/01/2020  1   1.1 1.5 1.2 1   0.9
3   04/01/2020  1   1.1 1.5 1.2 1   0.9
```

Comment: This solution also worked perfectly for me! thank you for your time helping me