# Python: Write a nested loop to test whether a series of string values is present in the column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, nested-loops

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`. `df1` has a column called `'comments'` that contains a string. `df2` has a column called `'labels'` that contains smaller strings. I am trying to write a function that searches `df1['comments']` for the strings contained in `df2['labels']` and creates a new variable for `d1` called `df1['match']` that is `True` if `df1['comments']` contains any of the strings in `df2['labels']` and `False` if `df1['comments']` does not contain any of the strings in `df2['labels']`.

I'm trying to use `df.str.contains('word', na=False)` to solve this problem and I have managed to create the column `df1['match']` searching for one specific string using the following function:

`df1['match'] = df1['comment'].str.contains('mystring', na=False)`

However, I struggle to write a function that iterates over all the words in `df2['label']` and creates a `df1['match']` with `True` if any of the words in `df2['label']` are present and `False` otherwise.

This is my attempt at writing the loop:

`for comment in df1['comment']:`

```
   for word in df2['label']:
       if df1['comment'].str.contains(word, na=False)=True:
          df1['match']=True
                             #(would need something to continue to next comment if there is a match)
          else:
              df1['match']=False   #(put value as false if there none of the items in df2['label' is contained in df1['comment']``
```

Any help would be greately appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a multiple substring search through a regex search using pipe. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/select-by-partial-string-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

```
df1['match'] = df['comment'].str.contains('|'.join(df2['label'].values), na=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much it will help but better way to compare is below way. It's efficient.

If `df1['match']` you want to mention row by row then code will need some change . But I think you got what actually you wanted.

```
test1=df2['label'].to_list()
test2=df1['comments'].to_list()
flag = 0
if(set(test1).issubset(set(test2))): 
    flag = 1

if (flag) : 
    df1['match']=True
else : 
    df1['match']=False
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this but it returns False for all the values in df1['match']. Don't I still have to write some kind of loop as I want df1['match']=1 if the observation contains any of the values in df2['label']?

Answer (score 0):

Try this If this helps

```
df2['match'] = "False"

for idx, word in enumerate(df2['labels']):
    q = df1['comment'][idx:].str.contains(word)
    df2['match'][idx] = q[idx]
```

Comment: I have posted my full code let me know if this is what you want, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code let me know if this is what you are asking for

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'comment': ["abcd efgh ijk", "lmno pqrst uvwxyz", "123456789 4567895062"]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df1)

d = {'labels': ["efgh", "pqrst", "12389"]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df2)

df2['match'] = "False"


for idx, word in enumerate(df2['labels']):
    q = df1['comment'][idx:].str.contains(word)
    df2['match'][idx] = q[idx]

print("final df2")
print(df2)
```