# str.contains search in a pandas column for multiple strings separated by a comma

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
Company               keywords

A                     SOFTWARE, IOT, PLATFORM, ENERGY, OPEN SOURCE
B                     ENERGY, PUBLIC UTILITIES, HARDWARE, SOFTWARE
C                     ENERGY, SOFTWARE, ELECTROMOBILITY, EMISSIONS
D                     HARDWARE, DATA, API, SOFTWARE, DATA PLATFORM
E                     ENERGY, SOFTWARE, ELECTROMOBILITY, DATA
```

I would like to create two separate dataframe
1-with the keyword 'SOFTWARE' without the keyword 'HARDWARE'
2 The combination of both i.e 'SOFTWARE' and 'HARDWARE'

The desired output should look like the following:

```
df_software
Company               keywords

A                     SOFTWARE, IOT, PLATFORM, ENERGY, OPEN SOURCE
C                     ENERGY, SOFTWARE, ELECTROMOBILITY, EMISSIONS
E                     ENERGY, SOFTWARE, ELECTROMOBILITY, DATA

df_software_hardware

   

B                     ENERGY, PUBLIC UTILITIES, HARDWARE, SOFTWARE
D                     HARDWARE, DATA, API, SOFTWARE, DATA PLATFORM
```

I can easily find

```
df_software=df[df['Keywords'].str.contains('(SOFTWARE)')]
```

but it also give rows with 'HARDWARE' entries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can see the details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/select-by-partial-string-from-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np

# Boolean indices of rows including word SOFTWARE
ind_df_software=df["keywords"].str.contains("SOFTWARE")

# Boolean indices of rows including word HARDWARE
ind_df_hardware=df["keywords"].str.contains("HARDWARE")

df_software=df.loc[np.logical_and(ind_df_software, ~ind_df_hardware)]
df_software_hardware=df.loc[np.logical_and(ind_df_software, ind_df_hardware)]
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> df_software

  Company                                      keywords
0       A  SOFTWARE, IOT, PLATFORM, ENERGY, OPEN SOURCE
2       C  ENERGY, SOFTWARE, ELECTROMOBILITY, EMISSIONS
4       E       ENERGY, SOFTWARE, ELECTROMOBILITY, DATA

>>> df_software_hardware

  Company                                      keywords
1       B  ENERGY, PUBLIC UTILITIES, HARDWARE, SOFTWARE
3       D  HARDWARE, DATA, API, SOFTWARE, DATA PLATFORM
```

Comment: Working as desired, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df_software=df[~df['Keywords'].str.contains('(HARDWARE)') & df['Keywords'].str.contains('(SOFTWARE)')]
```