# find if a substring is contained in an index in a Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to iterate through a dataframe, where I've indexed the data using a series of string names. I want to search these indices for a certain substring and then place all those rows that have the substring into another dataframe.

suppose my original dataframe is called `df.`

I've tried:

```
find_cat = df[df.str.contains("cat")]
```

And also tried

```
find_cat = 

for row_index,row in df.iterrows():
    if row_index.str.contains("cat", na=True):
        find_cat(append(row)
```

Both of these fail [try 1 = error in syntax, try 2 = an empty dataframe.

Quite new to python and Pandas....any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: [This answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55335207/4909087) shows how to select by partial substring search.

Comment: Thank you @cs95.  I'm having some difficulty because somehow it's not letting me search through a column because the data is indexed by name but "Name" is not showing as a column

Comment: Use `df = df.reset_index()` to convert the index into a column. Otherwise you can use `df.index.str.contains(...)`