# Checking if list item is in a dataset in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to get rid of rows in a dataset that do not contain states from the list:

state_names = ["Alaska", "Alabama", "Arkansas", "American Samoa", "Arizona", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "District of Columbia", "Delaware", "Florida"......]

The column name that would contain a state name is called "place," however, it is not just the state name. For example, I want to keep the row that contains "26km S of Redoubt Volcano, Alaska" but I want to get rid of the row that contains "10km WNW of Progreso, Mexico" in the "place" column. How would I go about doing this using dropna()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to match substrings in string, if your data is small and not concerned with the performance. Otherwise look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/select-by-partial-string-from-a-pandas-dataframe).

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"place": ["26km S of Redoubt Volcano, Alaska", "10km WNW of Progreso, Mexico", "Arkansassawbad", "Hotel California Royale", "Something Wrong"]})

state_names = [
    "Alaska",
    "Alabama",
    "Arkansas",
    "American Samoa",
    "Arizona",
    "California",
    "Colorado",
    "Connecticut",
    "District of Columbia",
    "Delaware",
]
df = df.loc[df["place"].str.contains('|'.join(state_names))]
```

**Output:**

```
                               place
0  26km S of Redoubt Volcano, Alaska
2                     Arkansassawbad
3            Hotel California Royale
```

**Explanation:**

[`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) does a regex match by default. Since we are looking for multiple words to be present in a column, we build the regex by joining words using `|` (OR operand) of regex.

**Reference:**

[Select by partial string from a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/select-by-partial-string-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think .dropna() will be enough to do the job.

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"place": ["26km S of Redoubt Volcano, Alaska", "10km WNW of Progreso, Mexico"]})

state_names = [
    "Alaska",
    "Alabama",
    "Arkansas",
    "American Samoa",
    "Arizona",
    "California",
    "Colorado",
    "Connecticut",
    "District of Columbia",
    "Delaware",
]

df["contain_state_names"] = df["place"].apply(
    lambda x: any([word for word in state_names if word in x])
)
print(df)

filtered = df.loc[df["contain_state_names"]]

print(filtered)
```

will print:

```sh
                               place  contain_state_names
0  26km S of Redoubt Volcano, Alaska                 True
1       10km WNW of Progreso, Mexico                False

                               place  contain_state_names
0  26km S of Redoubt Volcano, Alaska                 True
```

A quick explanation:

- .apply(): [Apply a function along an axis of the DataFrame.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)
- lambda: [A function that is defined without a name.](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/anonymous-function)
- any(): Takes an list of boolean values, returns True if any value is True
- .loc(): [Used to filter rows on a DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Answer (score 0):

#### Without `dropna()`

Although this first solution does not use the `dropna()` method it accomplishes the same goal cleanly.

An example dataframe based from your description:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

In  [1]: state_names = ["Alaska", "Alabama"] # substrings to find
        df = pd.DataFrame(data={'place': ["10km WNW of Progreso, Mexico","26km S of Redoubt Volcano, Alaska"]})
        df
Out [1]: 
    place
0   10km WNW of Progreso, Mexico
1   26km S of Redoubt Volcano, Alaska
```

The idea is to slice using the pandas string and the regex capability, specifically joining the list states with '|' which in regex terms means "Alaska" or "Alabama" ... This allows us to
only select rows with a state as a substring in the place column:

```
In  [2]: df = df[df.place.str.contains('|'.join(state_names))]
         df
Out [2]: 
    place
1   26km S of Redoubt Volcano, Alaska
```

#### With `dropna()`

This is one way to use `dropna()` to accomplish this although I find the first method simpler as this involves the extra (and unneeded) step of assigning null values to the cells that do not contain a state and then drop rows based on the "place" columns' null values:

```
In  [3]: df.loc[~df.place.str.contains('|'.join(state_names), na=False), 'place'] = np.nan
         df.dropna(subset=['place'])
Out [3]:
    place
1   26km S of Redoubt Volcano, Alaska
```