# Python : Find the Top 10 between multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, seaborn

I'd like to post the Top10 most present actors/actresses in American productions with an average score above 7.

I've tried several combinations and I've searched on stack but I really can't figure it out

```
df['actors'] = pd.Series(df['cast'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack().reset_index(drop=True))

top_actors = df[df['country'] == 'United States']

top_actors = df[df.actors != 'No Actors'].set_index('averageRating').actors.str.split(', ', expand=True).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
plt.figure(figsize=(13,7))
plt.title('Top 10 des acteurs américain')

sns.countplot(y = top_actors, order=top_actors.value_counts().index[:10], palette='Blues')
plt.show()
```

Comment: have you tried adapting the list comprehension approach to your problem?
```lang-python
top_actors_above_7_rating = [actor for actor in complete_list if actor.rating > 7.0]
```

Comment: No...I must admit that I am a beginner

Comment: Have you any idea, how can I solve my problem?

Comment: if you can read a line from the table and access the contents - then you can use the above approach.
Question is how exactly you are reading the lines and how they get stored.
If they get stored as objects - you will need to access appropriate attributes like ```object.attribute > 7.0```. If they get stored as list elements - you will need ```list[element_number] > 7.0```.
You might need to convert to float in case the values like '6.4' get stored as strings instead of floats.

Comment: this looks relevant to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/select-by-partial-string-from-a-pandas-dataframe?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone help me, so we can use a Pivot Table :

````
us_actors = df[df['country'] == 'United States']

rate_over_7 = us_actors[us_actors['averageRating'] >7]

actors = pd.Series(df['cast'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack().reset_index(drop=True))

table = pd.pivot_table(rate_over_7, values=['averageRating'], index=actors, aggfunc= np.mean)

top_10 = table.iloc[:10]
top_10_sort = top_10.sort_values(by=['averageRating'], ascending=False)

sns.barplot(data=top_10_sort, x="averageRating", y=top_10_sort.index)```
````

Answer (score 0):

this may help.

```
    df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
    df_ = df.copy()
    for i,r in df_.iterrows():
      if (r['averageRating'] < 7):
        df_.drop(i,inplace=True)
```

In the above-mentioned code, we are iterating through the rows and check if the 'averageRating' is less than 7, if that condition is true then we are dropping the entire row.