# Get most similar value from dataframe column to specific string python

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I want to find the most similar value from a dataframe column to a specified string , e.g. `a='book'`. Let's say the dataframe looks like: `df`

```
col1
wijk 00 book
Wijk a 
test
```

Now I want to return `wijk 00 book` since this is the most similar to `a`. I am trying to do this with the `fuzzywuzzy` package.

Therefore, I have a dataframe `A` with the values I want to have a similar one for. Then I use:

```
A['similar_value'] = A.col1.apply(lambda x: [process.extract(x, df.col1, limit=1)][0][0][0])
```

But when comparing a lot of strings, this takes too much time. Does anyone knows how to do this quickly?

Comment: How you define similarity here?

Comment: @ZalakBhalani the strings in the dataframe column should contain the string `a`

Comment: what's your current code with `fuzzywuzzy`? we can try to optimize that

Comment: I added my code

Comment: What is the process variable defined as?

Comment: @baqm _"the strings in the dataframe column should contain the string `a`"_ - that is **not** a similarity check. You could do it with a simple `.contains` check - `df[df['col1'].str.contains("book")]`, [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11531402/1431750).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select by partial string from a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/select-by-partial-string-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'str.contains' method to get the string which exact substring

```
df[df["column_name"].str.contains("book")].values[0][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [rapidfuzz](https://pypi.org/project/rapidfuzz/):

```
from rapidfuzz import process, fuzz

df = pd.DataFrame(['wijk 00 book', 'Wijk a', 'test'], columns=['col1'])

search_str = 'book'
most_similar = process.extractOne(search_str, df['col1'], scorer=fuzz.WRatio)
```

Output:

```
most_similar
('wijk 00 book', 90.0, 0)
```

This gives you the most similar string in the column as well as a score for how similar it is to your search string.

Comment: nice +1, much faster than my version using rapidfuzz with `apply()`