# Exact match resulting in error: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple columns, and one of them is named 'Message'. I am assigning a simple string to it 'test' on index 0

```py
df['Message'][0] = "test"
```

Now I need to check it in IF statement and if there is a match, I want print the content index 0 of 'Time' column. Following is my code snippet:

```py
if (df['Message'][0]).str.contains('test'):
    print(df['Time'][0])
```

For some reason I keep getting following error:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

I have checked that `type(df['Message'][0])` is returning as `'str'`

Also the complete df shows up as following:

```
1
df.dtypes
Out[190]:
Date       object
Time       object
Col2       object
Col3       object
Message    object
dtype: object
```

Appreciate any help on what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: `if 'test' in df['Message'][0]:` ?

Comment: _I have checked that type(df['Message'][0]) is returning as 'str'_. Does type 'str' have an attribute 'str'?

Comment: This addresses a similar issue [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/select-by-partial-string-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: In df.dtypes, 'Message' shows up as object. Not sure if thats what you asked @NicholasHunter

Comment: @NicholasHunter  See below my answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `str` method/object is for a Pandas Series and not for an element of a Series even though that element is a string.   By subscripting a series with `[0]` you are already getting an element of the series.  Such string element has no object/property/method called `str` and hence the error.

To test an element contains a substring, you can use the syntax that @Andrej Kesely suggests:

```
if 'test' in df['Message'][0]:
```

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks for the explanation. My code runs fine now with this change.