# Check if pandas string column contains multiple words, in any order

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string-matching

I am working on Twitter data and trying to find strings that contain more than one word.
The following line works for one word and with the OR condition.

```
tweets_text[tweets_text.str.contains("break")] #Find strings with the word break

tweets_text[tweets_text.str.contains("break|social|media")] #Find strings with either break or social, or media
```

I am trying to find the strings that have these three words ("break & social & media")

Comment: Do you care about the order in which 'break','social','media' can occur? There are 3! = 6 possible orders, in theory. Could 'break' occur between 'social' and 'media'?

Comment: Related: [Select by partial string from a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/select-by-partial-string-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df = pd.Series(['break', 'break media social', 'break media'])
```

Series:

```
0                 break
1    break media social
2           break media
```

extraciton:

```
tweets_text[tweets_text.str.contains('(?=.*break)(?=.*social)(?=.*media)')]
```

output:

```
1    break media social
```

Comment: Does this assume they occur in the strict order 'break', followed by 'social', 'media'?

Comment: it finds them regardless of location, I added text to show an example. the regex `?=.*` will find it anywhere

Comment: Ah okay, great.

Answer (score 1):

You can split them up like this:

```
tweets_text.loc[tweets_text.str.contains("break") & tweets_text.str.contains("social") & tweets_text.str.contains("media")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always add some additional parameters to ignore uppercase or lowercase letters, using `flags`. Using @[Rutger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68016999/16672014) 's code. Check the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for some additional parameters.

```
tweets_text.loc[tweets_text.str.contains("break", flags = re.IGNORECASE) & tweets_text.str.contains("social") & tweets_text.str.contains("media", flags = re.IGNORECASE)]
```

In addition to that you can do the same things by combining `lambda` function and `all`, as follows:

```
def find_words(data, list_of_words):
    function = lambda row: all(word.lower() in row.lower() 
                               for word in list_of_words)

    return data.loc[data[column_name].apply(function)]
```