# Make a column based on specific values from other column pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I got this dataframe

| Contact | Title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Dear Sir White, |
| 2 | Dear Madam Ford, |
| 3 | Dear Sir / Madam Hendricx, |

I want to make another column called 'Gender' based on the column 'Title'

| Contact | Title | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dear Sir White, | M |
| 2 | Dear Madam Ford, | F |
| 3 | Dear Sir / Madam Hendricx, | O |

So Dear Sir is M(ale)

Dear Madam is F(emale)

Dear Sir / Madam is O

I hope someone can help!

Comment: You want to clearly define how you want to identify gender from these salutations. Merely writing a regex seems less than sufficient for that kind of task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['title'].str.contains("Sir"), 'Gender'] = 'Male'
df.loc[df['title'].str.contains("Madam"), 'Gender'] = 'Female'
df.loc[df['title'].str.contains(" Sir / Madam"), 'Gender'] = '0'
```

also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/select-by-partial-string-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

```
g = []

for text in df.Title:
    if ' Sir / Madam' in text:
        g.append('O')
    elif 'Sir' in text:
        g.append('M')
    else:
        g.append('F')

df["Gender"] = g
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_func(text):
    if 'Sir / Madam' in text:
        return 'O'
    elif 'Madam' in text:
        return 'F'
    else:
        return 'M'

df['Gender'] = df['Title'].apply(my_func)
```