# Filter pandas dataframe if value of column is within a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I carefully read the post [Select by partial string from a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/select-by-partial-string-from-a-pandas-dataframe) but I think it doesn't address my problem. I need to filter rows of a dataframe if a row value can be found within the string.

Example, my table is:

```
Part_Number
A1127
A1347
```

I want to filter records if column value is within the string `ZA1127B.48`. The filtered dataframe should contain row `1`. (All the posts show how to check if row value contains a string.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.apply` + `in` operator:

```py
s = "ZA1127B.48"

print(df[df.apply(lambda x: x.Part_Number in s, axis=1)])
```

Prints:

```
  Part_Number
0       A1127
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using the apply function will help you to do what you want.

Try this line:

```
df[df["Part_Number"].apply(lambda x: x in "ZA1127B.48")]
```