# python: filter pandas DataFrame getting all the rows in which in any of the values the string contains a substring

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I would like to get the number of rows in which any of the values contain a space

My starting point is:

```
li = [['erer','sfsddf', 'dfdf dfdf'],['erer','sfs/ df', 'dfdf dfdf'],['erer','sfsd/df', 'dfdf dfdf'],['er/er','sfsddf', 'dfdf dfdf'],['er/er','sfsddf', 'dfdf dfdf'],['er er','sfsddf', 'dfdf dfdf']]
df = pd.DataFrame(li, columns=[str(i) for i in range(3)])
df.apply(lambda col: col.str.contains(' ', na=False), axis=1)
```

(following: [Filter pandas DataFrame by substring criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/filter-pandas-dataframe-by-substring-criteria))

But from that I dont know how to use that boolean DF to filter the original DF.
What I want is to filter out all the rows where the boleans are False, i.e. not having space.

Comment: You can use `any` after `apply`

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For filtering rows contains space use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for boolean mask and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.apply(lambda col: col.str.contains(' ', na=False), axis=1).any(axis=1)]
print (df1)
       0        1          2
0   erer   sfsddf  dfdf dfdf
1   erer  sfs/ df  dfdf dfdf
2   erer  sfsd/df  dfdf dfdf
3  er/er   sfsddf  dfdf dfdf
4  er/er   sfsddf  dfdf dfdf
5  er er   sfsddf  dfdf dfdf
```

If need count rows with space use [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) with `sum`:

```
df['sum'] = df.apply(lambda col: col.str.count(' '), axis=1).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
       0        1          2  sum
0   erer   sfsddf  dfdf dfdf    1
1   erer  sfs/ df  dfdf dfdf    2
2   erer  sfsd/df  dfdf dfdf    1
3  er/er   sfsddf  dfdf dfdf    1
4  er/er   sfsddf  dfdf dfdf    1
5  er er   sfsddf  dfdf dfdf    2
```