# If a special character exists, then display?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm learning python. I'm trying to identify rows of data where the string value includes a special character.

```
import pandas as pd
cn = pd.read_excel(f"../Files/df.xlsx", sheet_name='Values')
cn = cn[['DestinationName']]
special_characters = "!@#$%^&*()-+?_=,<>/"

cn['Special Characters'] = ["Y" if any(c in special_characters for c in cn) else "N"]
```

Basically, I'd like to either only display rows that include any of the special characters, or create a separate column to show whether Yes (it includes a special character) or No. For example, Red & Blue has the "&" character so it should be flagged as Yes, while RedBlue shouldn't.

I'm a little stuck, and any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/filter-pandas-dataframe-by-substring-criteria)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using sets on this specific task :

1. Creating a set of your list of special characters
2. Create a new column, which contains the following boolean : "the intersection of special_characters and the string of column "Destination Name" is non empty"

It should look like this:

```
special_characters_set = set(list(special_characters))
cn["Special Characters"] = cn["DestinationName"].apply(lambda x : len(set(list(x)).intersect(special_characters_set)) != 0)
```

Where

```
# list('hello') = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'] # ordered and repetitions
# set(list('hello')) = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'o'} # non ordered and no repetitions
```

Keep in mind that the .apply() method is not really the most computationally efficient to manipulate dataframes.