# Filter Pandas dataframe based on combination of keywords

Tags: python, pandas

Supposed I have as dataframe as,

|  | Role A | Role B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Project Viewer | Project Manager |
| 1 | Project Viewer | Project Developer |
| 2 | Project Viewer | Project Approver |
| 3 | Project Manager | Project Developer |
| 4 | Project Manager | Project Approver |
| 5 | Project Developer | Project Approver |

And I have these combinations of keywords/filter words

|  | Combo 1 | Combo 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | approve | create |
| 1 | authorize | develop |
| 2 | permit | manage |

So I want an output whereby the dataframe at the top gets filtered and only combinations that contains these keywords are left. Something like this:

|  | Role A | Role B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Project Manager | Project Approver |
| 1 | Project Developer | Project Approver |

If someone has the solution please help

Comment: Should combo 1 pair with role a and combo 2 with role b ? And are you sure about your expected output?

Comment: You need to be a bit clearer about the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Let me share you a sample, you can use it based on your needs;

```
import pandas as pd
 
combo_1 = [...]
combo_2 = [...]
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(...)
print(data_frame[dataframe["Role A"].isin(combo_1) & dataframe["Role B"].isin(combo_2)])
```

Comment: This won't work: the strings in the `Combo 1`/`Combo 2` are potential _substrings_ of the ones in `Role A`/`Role B`.

Comment: Hmm, did you see this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/filter-pandas-dataframe-by-substring-criteria

Answer (score 0):

May be reading https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html will help.  To filter things out you can (ab)use an "inner" join on the first with the third pd.

However, what you want with the second pd is not clear to me.