# Filter on a pandas string column as numeric without creating a new column

Tags: python, pandas

This is a quite easy task, however, I am stuck here. I have a dataframe and there is a column with type string, so characters in it:

```
Category
AB00
CD01
EF02
GH03
RF04
```

Now I want to treat these values as numeric and filter on and create a subset dataframe. However, I do not want to change the dataframe in any way. I tried:

```
df_subset=df[df['Category'].str[2:4]<=3]
```

of course this does not work, as the first part is a string and cannot be evaluated as numeric and compared to 69.

I tried

```
df_subset=df[int(df['Category'].str[2:4])<=3]
```

but I am not sure about this, I think it is wrong or not the way it should be done.

Comment: `df['Category'].str[2:4]<='69'`? Are you comparing to `69` or to `3`?

Comment: maybe your problem is solved here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/filter-pandas-dataframe-by-substring-criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add type conversion to your expression:

```
df[df['Category'].str[2:].astype(int) <= 3]
```

---

```
  Category
0     AB00
1     CD01
2     EF02
3     GH03
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have leading zeros, you can directly use string comparison:

```
df_subset = df.loc[df['Category'].str[2:4] <= '03']
```

Output:

```
  Category
0     AB00
1     CD01
2     EF02
3     GH03
```