# How to check if keyword is present in title or not in Python?

Tags: python, keyword, keyword-search

I have a dataset which contains multiple keywords and I want to check if title contains the same key or not. it should be row by row partial match.

I have tried this code but it is not working for indic words/keys:

```py
for string in df['key']:
    test = df['title'].str.contains(string,case=False, na=False) 
    print(test)
```

**Sample dataset:**

[image: dataset]

**Expected Output:**

[image: output]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter pandas DataFrame by substring criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/filter-pandas-dataframe-by-substring-criteria)

Comment: @JonSG I tried this one but it does not work for indic words. it works for english words only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have Indic keyboard, but have you tried the easy solution:

```
for line in list_of_lines:
    if str(line['key']).lower() in str(line['title']).lower():
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')
```