# Substrings extractions based on a matched column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need a code that does 2 functions. **Update I added something to the requirements that I forgot**

1, if a substring if found on a list, it should tag it with a name, for example, if "0325" is found then in another column, it should add "animal_customer" and if no match is found, it should say "unknown" in a column that in this example is named, 'specie'

2, if the substring is found, then, on another column that has a long string, it should extract 1 substring (space separated) to the left and 3 substrings (also space separated) to the right. After that if found and added to another column, the column (in this case named story) is not necesary. Note that if there was no match in step 1, then this column should say "I.D. not found"

3, There is a chance that more than 1 tag will occur, I need all those that show up as lists in the column

Here is an example of the lists and how the inital table and result table should look

```
animal = ["0325", "9985"]

human = ["9984", "1859"]
```

Original Table ->

| name | species_id | story |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 010199840101 | based on research, human is from U.S. or nearby |
| Fido | 010199850101 | based on research, animal is from taiwan or nearby |
| E.T. | 010145660101 | based on research, E.T. is from mars or nearby |
| ManBearPig | 03259984010101 | based on research, human is from mars or nearby and animal is probably alien too |

Resulting table ->

| name | species_id | specie | origin_list | extract |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 010199840101 | human_customer | human | research, human is from U.S. |
| Fido | 010199850101 | animal_customer | animal | research, animal is from taiwan |
| E.T. | 010145660101 | unknown | none | I.D. Not found |
| manbearpig | 03259984010101 | "human_customer", "animal_customer" | "animal", "human" | "research, human is from mars", "and animal is probably alien" |

My attempt to fix this:

```
animal_df = df[df["species_id"].str.contains('|'.join(map(re.escape, animal)))]
animal_df["specie"] = "animal_customer"

human_df = df[df["species_id"].str.contains('|'.join(map(re.escape, human)))]

human_df["specie"] = "human_customer"

df_append = pd.concat(["human_df", "animal_df"])
```

Problem:

As you can see my attempt will identify and tag the row as if it contains an animal or a human, but wont show up the error if it does not match anything and also will add duplicates.

Comment: You are looking for Pandas str.contains, there are multiple answers using this solution, eg - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/filter-pandas-dataframe-by-substring-criteria

Answer (score 2):

I would use regex for this. First you need to find any of the values that identify a species. This can be done with `create_pattern` function that returns a regex pattern with named group. For simplicity I put all species mappings under the `species_mapping` dictionary, where the key represents the value you want to put into the df. Then all the patterns will be simply joined with pipe to create the regex `species_pattern`. The `map_species` function simply returns whatever regex group will be found first or "unknown". The last step is to map this function to the column `species_id` and store it in `species` column.

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

def create_pattern(name: str, values: list):
    return rf"(?P<{name}>{'|'.join(values)})"

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "name": ["Bob", "Fido", "E.T.", "ManBearPig"],
        "species_id": ['010199840101', '010199850101', '010145660101', '03259984010101']
    }
)

species_mapping = {
    "animal_customer": ["0325", "9985"],
    "human_customer": ["9984", "1859"],
}

joined_patterns = "|".join(create_pattern(name, values) for name, values in species_mapping.items())
species_pattern = re.compile(rf"({joined_patterns})+")
# will be like '((?P<animal_customer>0325|9985)|(?P<human_customer>9984|1859))+'

def map_species(species_id):
    m = species_pattern.search(species_id)
    if not m:
        return "unknown"
    return ",".join(group for group, value in m.groupdict().items() if value is not None)

df["species"] = df["species_id"].map(map_species)

print(df.to_string())

>>>           name      species_id                         species
>>>  0         Bob    010199840101                  human_customer
>>>  1        Fido    010199850101                 animal_customer
>>>  2        E.T.    010145660101                         unknown
>>>  3  ManBearPig  03259984010101  animal_customer, human_customer
```

In a similar way I would approach the second task.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution. I made a small change since I forgot that sometimes I need more than 1 tag. Could you update the answer accordingly? sorry about any issue.

Comment: OK I edited the solution: the only thing I needed to touch is the `species_pattern` which now needs to be enclosed in another group with + quantifier. And of course return all matches in `map_species` in some way. As in your example I simply joined them with comma, but I personally would leave them as a list.